# Can't get Gmail Contextual Gadget to Load

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

Help! I have looked at this over and over and it just wont load. I should see it show on every email but nothing. What did I miss?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ApplicationManifest xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/ApplicationManifest/2009">

  <!-- Support info to show in the marketplace & control panel -->
  <Support>
    <!-- URL explaining how customers get support. -->
    <Link rel="support" href="http://example.com" />
  </Support>

  <Edition id="SlidersExtractor"></Edition>

  <!-- Name and description pulled from message bundles -->
  <Name>Sliders 2</Name>
  <Description>Sliders</Description>


<!-- EXTRACTOR -->

<Extension id="SlidersExtractor" type="contextExtractor">
  <Name>Sliders</Name>
  <Url>google.com:SubjectExtractor</Url>
  <Triggers ref="Sliders"/>
  <Scope ref="emailSubject"/>
  <Container name="mail"/>
</Extension>


<!-- GADGET -->

<Extension id="Sliders" type="gadget">
  <Name>Sliders Gmail contextual gadget</Name>
      <Url>http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/117105461644591440890/sliders.xml</Url>
  <Container name="mail"/>
</Extension>


<!-- SCOPE -->

<Scope id="emailSubject">
  <Url>tag:google.com,2010:auth/contextual/extractor/SUBJECT</Url>
  <Reason>This application searches the Subject:"</Reason>
</Scope>


</ApplicationManifest>
```

And the Gadget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Sliders Gadget"
    description="Matches emails"
    height="20"
    author="me"
    author_email="james@example.com"
    author_location="everywhere">

    <!-- Declare feature dependencies. -->

    <!-- This one is not specific to Gmail contextual gadgets. -->
    <Require feature="dynamic-height"/>

   <Require feature="google.contentmatch">
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:SubjectExtractor
      </Param>
    </Require>

  </ModulePrefs>

  <!-- Define the content type and display location. The settings
   "html" and "card" are required for all Gmail contextual gadgets. -->
  <Content type="html" view="card">
    <![CDATA[
       Hello Sliders 2/18
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested your XML, but it may possibly be due to "Caching". Have you tried logging out and then logging again, or changing browser?

Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011614/2071317)!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011614/2071317